# Find combined max value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
{'date': '2019-10-21', 'hour': 3, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-21', 'hour': 4, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 0, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 1, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-21', 'hour': 0, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 0, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-19', 'hour': 5, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 0, 'id': '2'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 0, 'id': '3'}
```

I need to find for each id the latest date and hour so for instance for id=1 I want 2019-10-21 and 4 while I am getting the correct date but hour=5

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by all 3 columns and remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by column `id`:

```
L = [{'date': '2019-10-21', 'hour': 3, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-21', 'hour': 4, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 0, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 1, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-21', 'hour': 0, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 0, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-19', 'hour': 5, 'id': '1'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 0, 'id': '2'},
{'date': '2019-10-20', 'hour': 0, 'id': '3'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.sort_values(['id','date','hour'], ascending=[True, False, False]).drop_duplicates('id')
print (df)
        date  hour id
1 2019-10-21     4  1
7 2019-10-20     0  2
8 2019-10-20     0  3
```